# Copying a transparent image over another transparent image

Tags: php, image-processing, image-manipulation

Im trying to copy a image(a.png) on another.
Both contain transparency.
a.png shows up with a white background on save.

```
$base=imagecreatefrompng("base.png");
imagealphablending( $base, false );
imagesavealpha( $base, true );
$temp=imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
imagecopymerge($base,$temp,64,144,0,0,16,16,100);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$base=imagecreatefrompng("base.png");
imagealphablending( $base, true );
imagesavealpha( $base, true );
$temp=imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
imagecopy($base,$temp,64,144,0,0,16,16);
```

Comment: @GUIpsp Try running the function on this page: http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/overlay_image . Is that the effect you are looking for?

Comment: Yes thats it i was using imagecopymerge instead of imagecopy, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, all transparent pixels in $temp as coped over as black. With both imagecopy() and imagecopymerge() and imagecopymerge_alpha()